# How to acces an instance of a class from another class?

Tags: c#

I have the following code:

```
public class UnitManager
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Firstname { get; set; }

    public UnitManager(string name, string firstname)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Firstname = firstname;
    }
}

class Other
{
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var player1 = new UnitManager("p1Name", "p1FirstName");

        var player2 = new UnitManager("p2Name", "p2FirstName");
    }
}
```

So, I have created **2** objects in the `Program` class.
what I'd like to do is access those instances from inside the `Other` class to // do stuff.

For example, access player name, put a title in his name, then assess player2 and put another title.

please, keep in mind, this is just an exemple, i'm not actually planning on using this, i'm just trying to grasp the concept.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can write `UnitManager` a property in  `Other` class, set the `UnitManager`

```
public class Other
{
    public UnitManager manager1{ get; set; }
}
```

or write a method the pass `UnitManager` instance as parameter.

```
public class Other
{
    public void SetTitle(UnitManager m1) {
        // do your logic
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you might want something like this:

```
public class UnitManager
{
public string Name { get; set; }
public string Firstname { get; set; }

public UnitManager(string name, string firstname)
{
    this.Name = name;
    this.Firstname = firstname;
}

}


public class Other
{
     public void doSomething(UnitManager myUnit) {
             //do something with each unit manager
     }
}

public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
{
    //create an object of type UnitManager and place it into variable player1
    var player1 = new UnitManager("p1Name", "p1FirstName");
    //create an object of type UnitManager and place it into variable player2
    var player2 = new UnitManager("p2Name", "p2FirstName");

    //create an instance of the class Other
    Other ot = new Other();

    //call the method within the instantiated class ot (of type Other) and
    //pass it the instance of the object UnitManager with a name
    //of player1
    result1 = ot.doSomething(player1);
    result2 = ot.doSomething(player2);
}
}
```

Comment: You should explain your code to make your answer more valuable.

Comment: OK - I added some comments but it looks like you got your answer below. Please make sure to give the writer credit for the answer so they get points for trying to help you. Regards

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, i finally understood :)

Here's how i got it working with your help:

```
public class UnitManager
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Firstname { get; set; }

    public UnitManager(string name, string firstname)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Firstname = firstname;
    }
}

class Other
{
    public static void AddTitle(UnitManager myUnit)
    {
        var titlePlusFullName = ("The Legendary" + " " + myUnit.Name + " " + myUnit.Firstname);
        myUnit.Name = titlePlusFullName;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        var player1 = new UnitManager("john", "smith");

        var player2 = new UnitManager("jen", "doe");

        Other oT = new Other();

        Other.AddTitle(player1);
        Console.WriteLine("Player 1 name: " + player1.Name);
    }
}
```

it displays full name + title.

Answer (score 0):

If you have *exactly* `2` instances (players), why not *create* them within `UnitManager`?

```
// sealed: since we have 2 instances only we don't want to
// inherit (and create) derived classes
public sealed class UnitManager
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Firstname { get; set; }

    // private: since we have 2 intances only we don't want to expose the constructor
    private UnitManager(string name, string firstname)
    {
        this.Name = name;
        this.Firstname = firstname;
    }

    // Think over renaming these fields: say, Player and Computer
    public static readonly UnitManager Player1 = new UnitManager("p1Name", "p1FirstName");
    public static readonly UnitManager Player2 = new UnitManager("p2Name", "p2FirstName");
}
```

Then address them as `UnitManager.Player1` (`UnitManager.Player2`) e.g.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        UnitManager.Player1.Name = "First Name";
        UnitManager.Player2.Name = "Second Name";

        ...
    }
}
```

Or even (with a help of *static import*):

```
using static MyNamepace.UnitManager;

...

class Other
{
    public void DoSomething() 
    {
        // We don't have now put it as UnitManager.Player1 
        string name1 = Player1.Name;
        ...  
    }
}
```

Comment: actually, i didn't think so far, but i like your approach, it makes it feels easier to manipulate data this way, thanks!